# How to print a single backslash in python in a string?

Tags: python

In python (3x version)

```
'\' # this is error no doubt
'\\' # this prints two backslashes ,i.e., '\\'
r'\' # this also gives error
'anytext \ anytext' # gives 'anytext \\ anytext'
```

`r` and `R` tried both but didn't work
tried to escape the escape character `\` ,i.e., `'\\'` but didn't work [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8Da8.png)

Comment: `'\\'` should work

Comment: Please post the actual code, not just the strings you are trying.

Comment: this does not work see it prints `0.60\textbackslash pm0.073` I want `0.60\pm0.073`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IDLE (Python's Integrated Development and Learning Environment), expression values have their ***representation*** echoed to stdout.

As https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html explains:

> The `repr` function is used for interactive echo of expression values.
>   It returns an altered version of the input string in which control
>   codes, some BMP codepoints, and all non-BMP codepoints are replaced
>   with escape codes.

If you want to print a string, use the `print()` function. Otherwise you'll get its **representation**.

Consider the following code entered into IDLE:

```
>>> hitman_str = "Agent \ 47"
>>> print(hitman_str) # We see only one slash when using print
Agent \ 47
>>> hitman_str # This shows the representation, which shows two slashes
'Agent \\ 47'
>>> print(repr(hitman_str)) # Same as above
'Agent \\ 47'
```

There are multiple ways to get a string with only one slash:

```
single_slash1 = "\\"
>>> print(single_slash1)
\
>>> single_slash2 = "\ "[0]
>>> print(single_slash2)
\
>>> single_slash1 == single_slash2
True
```

Similarly, there are multiple ways to get a string with two consecutive slashes:

```
>>> two_slashes1 = "\\\\"
>>> print(two_slashes1)
\\
>>> print(repr(two_slashes1))
'\\\\'
>>> two_slashes1
'\\\\'
>>> len(two_slashes1)
2
>>> two_slashes2 = r"\\"
>>> print(two_slashes2)
\\
>>> print(repr(two_slashes2))
'\\\\'
>>> two_slashes2
'\\\\'
>>> len(two_slashes2)
2
```

We can confirm `hitman_str` only has one slash:

```
>>> hitman_str.count(single_slash1)
1
```

We can iterate through the string and print each character and its Unicode code point.
As expected, this shows only one slash:

```
>>> for char in hitman_str:
    print(char, ord(char))


A 65
g 103
e 101
n 110
t 116
  32
\ 92
  32
4 52
7 55
```

Raw strings are very handy, especially for Windows paths if you don't wanna use `os.path` or `pathlib`:

```
>>> filename = r"C:\Users\Lee Hong\Documents\New Letters\Impatient 1999-06-14.txt" # Works fine
>>> filename = "C:\Users\Lee Hong\Documents\New Letters\Impatient 1999-06-14.txt" # Error
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
>>> raw_str = r"This \\\has \11 \\slashes \\and \no \line \break"
>>> print(raw_str)
This \\\has \11 \\slashes \\and \no \line \break
>>> raw_str.count(single_slash1)
11
```

For more information, including a list of escape sequences to watch out for, refer to https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

Comment: this does not work see it prints `0.60\textbackslash pm0.073` I want `0.60\pm0.073`

Comment: If you want to print `0.60\pm0.073`, you can use a raw string and a single backslash (`print(r"0.60\pm0.073")`), or a just plain string and two backslashes (`print("0.60\\pm0.073")`).

Answer (score -1):

If I am understanding your questions correctly, like this: `print("\\")`?

Comment: Question is vague since that obviously prints a single backslash, but it's too simple so hence the question mark.

Comment: but it's not printing a single backslash as I expected also

Comment: Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 09:23:15) 
[Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print("\\")
\

Comment: please see the image I provided , in third input line i tried this literally

Comment: I got it , i was printing without using print function