# How to print a literal backslash to get \pm in a pandas data frame to generate a proper error bars in a latex table in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, latex, backslash

I have obviously seen [How to print a single backslash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095796/how-to-print-a-single-backslash) and related duplicates [can't print '\' (single backslash) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24278190/cant-print-single-backslash-in-python), [How to print a single backslash in python in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56689741/how-to-print-a-single-backslash-in-python-in-a-string), [Quoting backslashes in Python string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301068/quoting-backslashes-in-python-string-literals).

But I think my issue is that I have pandas involved and it is not generating the right latex table I need. I get:

```
  Initialization Test Accuracy
0         Random  0.200+-0.029
1        Random2    0.200+-0.0
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
Initialization & Test Accuracy \\
\midrule
        Random & 0.200\textbackslash pm0.029 \\
       Random2 &   0.200\textbackslash pm0.0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

but I need:

```
  Initialization Test Accuracy
0         Random  0.200+-0.029
1        Random2    0.200+-0.0
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
Initialization & Test Accuracy \\
\midrule
        Random & 0.200 \pm 0.029 \\
       Random2 &   0.200 \pm 0.0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

how do I have pandas print the right latex table for me?

full script:

```
import pandas as pd

# data = {'first_column':  ['first_value', 'second_value', ...],
#         'second_column': ['first_value', 'second_value', ...],
#          ....
#         }

import pandas as pd

#from uutils import put_pm_to_pandas_data

def put_pm_to_pandas_data(data: dict) -> dict:
    """
    Change the +- to \pm for latex display.

    ref:
        - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70008992/how-to-print-a-literal-backslash-to-get-pm-in-a-pandas-data-frame-to-generate-a
    """
    for column_name, data_values in data.items():
        # data[column_name] = [data_value.replace('+-', r'\pm') for data_value in data_values]
        data[column_name] = [data_value.replace('+-', r'\\pm') for data_value in data_values]
        # data[column_name] = [data_value.replace('+-', '\pm') for data_value in data_values]
    return data

data = {
    'Initialization': ['Random',
                       'Random2',
                       ],

    'Test Accuracy': ['0.200+-0.029',
                      '0.200+-0.0',
                      ],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
data = put_pm_to_pandas_data(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df.to_latex(index=False))
```

Comment: shouldn't `r'\pm'` be `r'\\pm'?

Comment: @QuangHoang that print `x &  y &      0.20\textbackslash \textbackslash pm0.0 \\` so I don't think so. Will update with all my current attempts.

Comment: pass `escape=False` to `to_latex` to prevent conversion of `\ ` to `\textbackslash`.

Comment: @QuangHoang that worked. How did it occur to you to do that? probably because pandas was the issue so the first place to look was in the pandas stuff, starting in the `to_latex`?

Comment: @QuangHoang btw how do I make it into a png latex table directly from python?

Comment: 1) because I saw `\textbackslash` instead of `\ ` so I looked up the function's signature if there is an option. 2) no idea about `png`.

Comment: As an aside, `put_pm_to_pandas_data` already *modifies the input dictionary*, so there is no need to return or reassign it. It is considered better style in Python not to return it here.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment by Quang Hoang said:

> pass escape=False to to_latex to prevent conversion of \  to \textbackslash