# How does one generate latex table images with proper equations from python pandas data frame directly?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, latex

Related to my recent question on printing `\pm` in latex with pandas [How to print a literal backslash to get \pm in a pandas data frame to generate a proper error bars in a latex table in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70008992/how-to-print-a-literal-backslash-to-get-pm-in-a-pandas-data-frame-to-generate-a?noredirect=1#comment123756707_70008992) I also wanted to display the table with the equations being shown correctly but instead I get the literal `\pm` in my table (+ it has a weird shape).

[image]

Is there a way to convert my data frame with equations to a png latex directly from python and save it as an image?

script

```py
import pandas as pd

# data = {'first_column':  ['first_value', 'second_value', ...],
#         'second_column': ['first_value', 'second_value', ...],
#          ....
#         }

import pandas as pd

from uutils import put_pm_to_pandas_data

 data = {
     'Initialization': ['Random',
                        'Random2',
                        ],

     'Test Accuracy': ['0.200+-0.029',
                       '0.200+-0.0',
                       ],
 }

# - to pandas table
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70009242/how-does-one-generate-latex-table-images-with-proper-equations-from-python-panda

# - to latex
data = put_pm_to_pandas_data(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df.to_latex(index=False, escape=False))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import table

# ax = plt.subplot(111, frame_on=False) # no visible frame
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)  # hide the x axis
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)  # hide the y axis

# table(ax, df)  # where df is your data frame
table(ax, df)  # where df is your data frame

plt.show()

# plt.savefig('mytable.png')
```

related:

- [How to save a pandas DataFrame table as a png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634238/how-to-save-a-pandas-dataframe-table-as-a-png)
- [How to print a literal backslash to get \pm in a pandas data frame to generate a proper error bars in a latex table in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70008992/how-to-print-a-literal-backslash-to-get-pm-in-a-pandas-data-frame-to-generate-a?noredirect=1#comment123756707_70008992)

Comment: `\pm` is a math command, you need to wrap the cells in `$...$` so matplotlib will render them.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide us with the definition of `put_pm_to_pandas_data`. But here is a solution using `DataFrame.replace`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import table

def put_pm_df(df):
    return df.replace("\+-", r"$\pm$", regex=True)
    
data = {
     'Initialization': ['Random',
                        'Random2',
                        ],
     'Test Accuracy': ['0.200+-0.029',
                       '0.200+-0.0',
                       ],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

df = put_pm_df(df)
print(df)

print(df.to_latex(index=False, escape=False))

ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)  # hide the x axis
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)  # hide the y axis

table(ax, df) 

plt.show()
```

**Output**

```
# initial df

  Initialization Test Accuracy
0         Random  0.200+-0.029
1        Random2    0.200+-0.0

# result of put_pm_df(df)

  Initialization    Test Accuracy
0         Random  0.200$\pm$0.029
1        Random2    0.200$\pm$0.0

# df.to_latex(index=False, escape=False)

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
Initialization &    Test Accuracy \\
\midrule
        Random &  0.200$\pm$0.029 \\
       Random2 &    0.200$\pm$0.0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

[image]